# How can I use observeEvent capture the HTML input id in shiny?

Tags: html, r, shiny

How can I use observeEvent capture the HTML input id in shiny ?

```
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage( HTML('<input type="button" name = "b1" value="Travel time"/>')),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$b1, {
      print(paste("This will only be printed once; all",
                  "subsequent button clicks won't do anything"))
    }, once = TRUE)

  }
)
```

I want to implement the function use HTML in shiny that when I clicked the 'Travel time',the event can be observeed.

Comment: `name` is not `id`, you have to set an `id`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I changed the 'name' to 'id', but it not worked.

Comment: Why don't you use an `actionButton` ?

Comment: It is a long story, for example actionButton can not added into DT table.

Comment: Try to add `class = "action-button"`.

Comment: Still not work :-(

Comment: please look into the package `shinyjs` you will need that to solve this problem

Comment: This is `<button></button>`, not `<input/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add a package:

```r
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage( 
    HTML('<button type="button" id="b1" class="action-button">Travel time</button>')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$b1, {
      print(paste("This will only be printed once; all",
                  "subsequent button clicks won't do anything"))
    }, once = TRUE) 
  }

)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with the `shinyjs` package

```
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    HTML('<input type="button" id = "b1" value="Travel time"/>')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    shinyjs::onclick(
      "b1",
      {
        shinyjs::disable(id = "b1")
        print(paste("This will only be printed once; all",
                    "subsequent button clicks won't do anything"))
      }
    )
    
  }
)
```

Hope this helps!!